# Providing Declarative data for controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu, custom-controls, custom-server-controls

I am in the process of learning Server Controls Development and looking for proper instructions to enable setting the data declaratively through source. For example the dropdownlist control provides declarative data like below

```
<asp:DropDownList id="dropdown" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem text="Project Initiation" value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem text="Documentation" value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

similarly i am looking for declaratively providing data to my simple menu control that displays image surrounded by  image like below (the output markup) from a datasource

```
<a>
 <img src="" />
</a>
```

Please do not point me to a link, the least anyone can do is that. I would like a clear explanation of what needs to be done for providing such functionality.
I would like my final source to look like below

```
<asp:sidebar runat="server" id="sb">
 <asp:sidebaritem navigateurl="" imageurl="" label=""></asp:sidebaritem>
</asp:sidebar>
```

sidebar item class is defined below and i have a property too

#### class

```
public class SidebarItem
 {
   private string _navigateUrl;

   public string NavigateUrl
    {
       get { return _navigateUrl; }
       set { _navigateUrl = value; }
    }
    . . . 
 }
```

#### property

```
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
[NotifyParentProperty(true)]
public ICollection<SidebarItem> Items
{
    get { return _sidebarItems; }
    set { _sidebarItems = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you are looking for is here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9txe1d4x.aspx

As you've asked for more than just a link, here's an example solution specific to your scenario:

```
[
AspNetHostingPermission(SecurityAction.Demand,
    Level = AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal),
AspNetHostingPermission(SecurityAction.InheritanceDemand,
    Level = AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal),
DefaultProperty("Items"),
ParseChildren(true, "Items"),
ToolboxData("<{0}:SideBar runat=\"server\"> </{0}:SideBar>")
]
public class SideBar : WebControl
{
    private ArrayList itemsList;

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    //[Editor(typeof(ContactCollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty)]
    public ArrayList Items
    {
        get
        {
            if (itemsList == null)
            {
                itemsList = new ArrayList();
            }
            return itemsList;
        }
    }

    protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Ul);
        foreach (object o in itemsList)
        {
            SideBarItem item = (SideBarItem)o;
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Li);
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, item.NavigateUrl);
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.A);
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Src, item.ImageUrl);
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Img);
            writer.RenderEndTag(); // Img
            writer.RenderEndTag(); // A
            writer.RenderEndTag(); // Li
        }
        writer.RenderEndTag(); // Ul
    }
}


[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class SideBarItem
{
    public SideBarItem()
        : this(String.Empty, String.Empty, String.Empty)
    {
    }

    public SideBarItem(string imgUrl, string navUrl, string label)
    {
        ImageUrl = imgUrl;
        NavigateUrl = navUrl;
        Label = label;
    }

    [DefaultValue("")]
    [NotifyParentProperty(true)]
    public String ImageUrl { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue("")]
    [NotifyParentProperty(true)]
    public String NavigateUrl { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue("")]
    [NotifyParentProperty(true)]
    public String Label { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the ASPX file would be as such:
Referenced

```
<%@ Register Assembly="MyProject" Namespace="MyProject" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

Implemented

```
    <cc1:SideBar ID="SideBar1" runat="server">
        <cc1:SideBarItem ImageUrl="#" NavigateUrl="#" />
        <cc1:SideBarItem ImageUrl="#" NavigateUrl="#" />
    </cc1:SideBar>
```